# How to bind your keys to keymaps that aren't loaded yet?

Tags: key-bindings, keymap, use-package

I use [`use-package`](https://github.com/jwiegley/use-package) to manage installed packages and [`bind-key`](https://github.com/jwiegley/use-package/blob/master/bind-key.el) to assign actions to custom keys that I like.

I override most of the default Emacs keybinding (e.g. <kbd>C-n</kbd> becomes <kbd>M-k</kbd>, <kbd>C-p</kbd> becomes <kbd>M-i</kbd>), but I'm OK with other modes overriding my keybinding scheme. Sometimes, I want my keybinding persist, however. I want <kbd>M-k</kbd> mean something else, than in default Gnus or Helm.

However they all conflict with each other on Emacs startup, because I can't add a binding to a keymap, if it doesn't exist (because `use-package` sometimes defers loading of a package). E.g., the following commands throw errors (e.g. `(void-variable helm-map)`), because Helm and Gnus aren't yet fully loaded.

```el
(bind-key "M-Y" 'helm-end-of-buffer helm-map)
(bind-key "M-k" 'helm-next-line helm-find-files-map)
(bind-key "M-s" 'other-window gnus-summary-mode-map)
```

I have all my `use-package` invocations in one file and `bind-key` for custom keybindings in another file. I don't want to put bindings into `use-package` calls, because maybe I want to publish my custom keybinding scheme as a standalone package. What if I want someone installing my scheme had Helm and Gnus local keybindings overriden too?

How do I manage mode-local keybindings using `bind-key`, so that all keys are set even if packages are loaded lately, and all key settings are inside one file?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can use `with-eval-after-load` to defer the key binding until after a certain module has been loaded (and thus defined the keymap):

```el
(with-eval-after-load "helm"
  (bind-key "M-Y" #'helm-end-of-buffer helm-map))
```

Use `C-h v helm-map` to find which module the keymap is defined in, and thus what to put in the string on the first line.

---

`with-eval-after-load` was introduced in Emacs 24.4. If you have an earlier Emacs version, you need to use `eval-after-load` instead, and put a single quote in front of the `bind-key` call:

```el
(eval-after-load "helm"
  '(bind-key "M-Y" #'helm-end-of-buffer helm-map))
```

If you want to put several `bind-key` calls in this form, with `with-eval-after-load` you just put them one after another, but with `eval-after-load` you need to wrap them all in a `progn`:

```el
(eval-after-load "helm"
  '(progn
     (bind-key "M-Y" #'helm-end-of-buffer helm-map)
     (bind-key "M-k" #'helm-next-line helm-find-files-map)))
```

Answer (score 9):

### Solution

In order to execute stuff after a given package is loaded, you need to put that after `:config` in `use-package`.

Here's an example using the snippet in your question:

**Snippet # 1**

```el
(use-package helm
  :config
  (progn
    (bind-key "M-Y" #'helm-end-of-buffer helm-map)
    (bind-key "M-k" #'helm-next-line helm-find-files-map)))

(use-package gnus
  :config
  (bind-key "M-s" #'other-window gnus-summary-mode-map))
```

---

#### Explanation

It is OK to have the below 2 snippets at different places in your emacs `init.el` or in any of the nested files loaded/required.

**Snippet # 2**

```el
(use-package gnus)
```

**Snippet # 3**

```el
(use-package gnus
  :config
  (bind-key "M-s" #'other-window gnus-summary-mode-map))
```

The reason is that it does not matter which of the above 2 snippets is executed first.

Here is why.. below is what Snippet # 3 expands to.

*You get the below by doing `M-x pp-macroexpand-last-sexp` when the point (cursor) is after the last closing parenthesis of that snippet.*

**Snippet # 4**

```el
(if (not (require 'gnus nil t))
    (ignore (message (format "Could not load %s" 'gnus)))
  (condition-case-unless-debug err
      (bind-key "M-s" #'other-window gnus-summary-mode-map)
    (error
     (ignore
      (display-warning 'use-package
                       (format "%s %s: %s" "gnus" ":config"
                               (error-message-string err))
                       :error))))
  t)
```

The above snippet basically means that

- `gnus` is required first and then the `bind-key` form is executed.
- If `gnus` is not found then you will see a message in the *Messages* buffer saying that that package couldn't be loaded.
- It will throw error if there is any problem in the executing `(bind-key "M-s" #'other-window gnus-summary-mode-map)`

Also if `gnus` is already required by *Snippet # 2* above and it is required again by *Snippet # 3*, it does not matter because `require` does not load a package again if it is already loaded.

---

### Reference

From the [`use-package` basics](https://github.com/jwiegley/use-package#the-basics) on its github,

> `:config` can be used to execute code after a package is loaded. In cases where loading is done lazily (see more about autoloading below), this execution is deferred until after the autoload occurs:

**Snippet # 5**

```el
(use-package foo
  :init
  (setq foo-variable t)
  :config
  (foo-mode 1))
```

Above executes the `:init` section ( `(setq foo-variable t)` ) **before** `foo` package is loaded. But `(foo-mode 1)` in the `:config` section is executed **after** `foo` is loaded.

Answer (score 3):

On the opposite of the other answers, I've always used hooks for this:

```
(defun my-company-maps()
  (define-key company-active-map "\C-x\M-h" 'company-show-doc-buffer)
  (define-key company-active-map "\C-n" 'company-select-next)
  (define-key company-active-map "\C-p" 'company-select-previous)
  (define-key company-active-map "\C-h" 'delete-backward-char))

(add-hook 'company-mode-hook 'my-company-maps)
```

Comment: Me too, I thought this was the preferred way of doing it.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are already using bind-key, straight from documentation of `bind-key.el`:

> If you want the keybinding to override all minor modes that may also bind
>    the same key, use the `bind-key*' form:

```el
(bind-key* "<C-return>" 'other-window)
```

> To unbind a key within a keymap (for example, to stop your favorite major mode from changing a binding that you don't want to override everywhere), use unbind-key:

```el
(unbind-key "C-c x" some-other-mode-map)
```

The last form breaks down if the keymap is currently undefined because the file defining `some-other-mode-map`has not yet be loaded. So you could put this in a `use-package` for `some-other-mode`(the package defining `some-other-mode-map`), or using `with-eval-after-load`:

```el
(with-eval-after-load 'some-other-mode
  (unbind-key "C-c x" some-other-mode-map))
```

An other alternative would be defining your own minor mode containing all bindings which should not be overridden by major modes:

```el
(defvar my-very-own-keymap (make-keymap) "my very own keymap.")

(define-key my-very-own-keymap (kbd "M-i") 'my-foo)

(define-minor-mode my-very-own-keys-minor-mode
  "Minor mode with my very own keybindings."
  t " my-own-keys" my-very-own-keymap)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a very old question, but I'll add an answer anyway.  I think all of the answers here miss the point of the original question.  use-package *defers* the loading of a package when you use `:bind` until one of the bound keys is pressed.  The problem is the bind keyword doesn't accept keymaps.  There is now a `:bind-keymap` keyword just for this:

https://jwiegley.github.io/use-package/keywords/#bind-keymap-bind-keymap

**Updated**

As an example, the combobulate package makes its own keymap with a bunch of keys like 'c' for clone.  It documents a way to set the prefix key, but if you wanted to do it yourself you could use something like:

```
(use-package combobulate
    :load-path "lisp"
    :bind-keymap ("C-x o" . combobulate-options-key-map))
```

If you tried to use `bind`, you'd get an error when you pressed C-x o.

(Remember, don't do this for combobulate.  Follow its instructions.  This is just an example.)

Comment: Could you please give a complete example of the use of `:bind-keymap` rather than just a link?  Doing so will make your post a stand-alone answer.