# Keybinding fails although it is not set

Tags: key-bindings

I'd like to use the key binding `M-n p` for `ess-swv-purl` in `.Rmd` documents and thus tried `(define-key global-set-key (kbd "M-n p") 'ess-swv-purl)`. If I'm in an `.Rmd` (Rmarkdown) document, `M-n p` still shows (`M-n p is undefined`).

I understand that global key settings are overwritten in many ways, but if the key combination is not bound, where is the problem? (I can execute the function with `M-x ess-swv-purl`). In case this helps, `C-h b` shows that `M-n` is a "Prefix Command" under `poly-markdown+r-mode`. I tried something like `(define-key poly-markdown+r-mode-map (kbd "M-n p") 'ess-swv-purl)` (which was just a guess, I don't know what should come after `define-key` in this case) but then get

```
Warning (initialization): An error occurred while loading ‘/Users/<user>/.emacs’:
Symbol's value as variable is void: poly-markdown+r-mode-map
```

Answer (score 2):

1. `M-n` is not a prefix key in the `global-map` (unless you define it as such).
2. If you want to define a key in `poly-markdown+r-mode-map` then that variable needs to be defined and bound to a keymap.  Use `with-eval-after-load` to bind the key in that map after (as soon as) its defining library is loaded.

Comment: Thanks for helping, Drew. I'm not sure how this is done. Is saw  [this link](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/12592/how-to-bind-your-keys-to-keymaps-that-arent-loaded-yet) and tried `(with-eval-after-load "poly-markdown+r-mode"
  (bind-key "M-n p" #'ess-swv-purl poly-markdown+r-mode-map))
`, but I still get  `M-n p is undefined`. And what do you mean by 'defining library'?

Comment: poly-markdown+R-mode is defined in the file poly-R, so your code should be: `(with-eval-after-load "poly-R"
  (bind-key "M-n p" #'ess-swv-purl
            poly-markdown+R-mode-map))`

Comment: Thanks, Tyler. If I open an .Rmd file now, it is not in polymode anymore and I see `File mode specification error: (void-function bind-key)` in the `*Messages*` buffer. I also tried `(with-eval-after-load "poly-R" (define-key poly-markdown+R-mode-map (kbd "M-n p") #'ess-swv-purl))` because `bind-key` requires an extra library I believe.

Comment: Yes, in the general case you need to *load* libraries before you can *use* their functions etc. Either load the library that defines `bind-key` or cause it to be loaded before you use that function. Or just use the vanilla Emacs function `define-key`, as you said - you don't need `bind-key`.

Comment: Since `M-n` is apparently a prefix key in the mode you want, it's likely that there is a specific variable bound to the keymap that `M-n` is bound to. In that case, just bind `p` in that keymap. You need to investigate the code a bit, to find out what you should be doing. You need to know what keymap you're binding a key in.